# React app on heroku works with http but not https

Tags: reactjs, http, heroku, https

I deployed some react boiler plate with create-react-app to heroku with successful deploy. it will not work with https, but works with http.

[image]

this is the error it is giving me and I don't think that my dependencies for create react app are bad, but I don't know what else it could be.

Comment: What message you get on the https? Do you have a custom domain? Do you have cloudflare?

Comment: @jbergeron no it is just a regular heroku app only boilerplate and I uploaded a react app to just see if i could get something working.

Comment: You don't want hot-reload turned on in production.

Comment: @Stephanfalcon did you try my answers about the wss?

Comment: @jbergeron I actually fixed it. but here is no way for me to change the way the socket is set up because I was not uploading my node_modules folder but I changed the version to an early one and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Your socket connexion is not secured.

Replace:

```
ws://timeclock03.herokuapp.com/sockjs-node
```

By:

```
wss://timeclock03.herokuapp.com/sockjs-node
```